# Tensorflow tf.cond evaluating both pedicate

Tags: tensorflow

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

isTrain = tf.placeholder(tf.bool)
user_input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

# ema = tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage(decay=.5)

with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    beta = tf.Variable(tf.ones([1]))

    batch_mean = beta.assign(user_input)
    ema = tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage(decay=0.5)
    ema_apply_op = ema.apply([batch_mean])
    ema_mean = ema.average(batch_mean)

    def mean_var_with_update():
        with tf.control_dependencies([ema_apply_op]):
            return tf.identity(batch_mean)

    mean = tf.cond(isTrain,
        mean_var_with_update,
        lambda: (ema_mean))

# ======= End Here ==========
saver = tf.train.Saver()
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

u_input = [[2], [3], [4] ]
for u in u_input:
    aa = sess.run([mean], feed_dict={user_input:u, isTrain: True })
    print("Train", aa)

for u in u_input:
    aa = sess.run([ema_mean], feed_dict={user_input:u, isTrain: False })
    print("Test correct", aa)

for u in u_input:
    aa = sess.run([mean], feed_dict={user_input:u, isTrain: False })
    print("Test", aa)
```

This code snippet should calculate the mean of user_input across training stage and output mean during testing stage.

This is the output result :

```
('Train', [array([ 2.], dtype=float32)])
('Train', [array([ 3.], dtype=float32)])
('Train', [array([ 4.], dtype=float32)])
('Test correct', [array([ 3.], dtype=float32)])
('Test correct', [array([ 3.], dtype=float32)])
('Test correct', [array([ 3.], dtype=float32)])
('Test', [array([ 2.5], dtype=float32)])
('Test', [array([ 2.75], dtype=float32)])
('Test', [array([ 3.375], dtype=float32)])
```

However, `ema_mean` always get evaluated when calling `sess.run([mean])` even if `isTrain = False`.

Is there any mistake in the code ?  tensorflow version is 0.7.1

Answer (score 1):

I think that is the same as [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37064128/133374). The `tf.control_dependencies` inside the conditionals will add the dependencies to the `tf.cond` itself.

So try to create the `ema_apply_op` inside the `mean_var_with_update` function.

Answer (score 0):

I've added some logging statements and `ema_mean` only seems to get evaluated when `isTrain` is false

```
tf.reset_default_graph()

isTrain = tf.placeholder(tf.bool)
user_input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

# ema = tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage(decay=.5)

with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    beta = tf.Variable(tf.ones([1]))

    batch_mean = beta.assign(user_input)
    ema = tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage(decay=0.5)
    ema_apply_op = ema.apply([batch_mean])
    ema_mean = ema.average(batch_mean)

    def mean_var_with_update():
        with tf.control_dependencies([ema_apply_op]):
            return tf.Print(tf.identity(batch_mean), ["mean_var_with_update"])
            #return tf.identity(batch_mean)

    mean = tf.Print(tf.cond(isTrain,
        mean_var_with_update,
        lambda: (tf.Print(ema_mean, ["ema_mean"]))),
                    ["evaluating mean", isTrain])

# ======= End Here ==========
saver = tf.train.Saver()
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

u_input = [[2], [3], [4] ]
for u in u_input:
    aa = sess.run([mean], feed_dict={user_input:u, isTrain: True })
    print("Train", aa)

for u in u_input:
    aa = sess.run([ema_mean], feed_dict={user_input:u, isTrain: False })
    print("Test correct", aa)

for u in u_input:
    aa = sess.run([mean], feed_dict={user_input:u, isTrain: False })
    print("Test", aa)
```

You see

```
[mean_var_with_update]
[evaluating mean][True]
[mean_var_with_update]
[evaluating mean][True]
[mean_var_with_update]
[evaluating mean][True]
[ema_mean]
[evaluating mean][False]
[ema_mean]
[evaluating mean][False]
[ema_mean]
[evaluating mean][False]
```

Note that the `Print` statement is evaluated after all the inputs have been evaluated so outer print statement is printed last

Comment: https://gist.github.com/24hours/0545f92d5407bcdd3106 `batch_mean` should not be evaluated if `isTrain=False` and `ema_mean` should not be evaluated if `isTrain=True`,  both get evaluated regardless of `isTrain` value. Is this the correct behaviour ?

Comment: @24hours: That is probably [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37063952/confused-by-the-behavior-of-tf-cond). Try to create the `ema_apply_op` inside the `mean_var_with_update` function.