# Confused by the behavior of `tf.cond`

Tags: tensorflow

I need a conditional control flow in my graph. If `pred` is `True`, the graph should call an op that updates a variable and then returns it, otherwise it returns the variable unchanged. A simplified version is:

```py
pred = tf.constant(True)
x = tf.Variable([1])
assign_x_2 = tf.assign(x, [2])
def update_x_2():
  with tf.control_dependencies([assign_x_2]):
    return tf.identity(x)
y = tf.cond(pred, update_x_2, lambda: tf.identity(x))
with tf.Session() as session:
  session.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
  print(y.eval())
```

However, I find that both `pred=True` and `pred=False` lead to the same result `y=[2]`, which means the assign op is also called when `update_x_2` is not selected by `tf.cond`. How to explain this? And how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

**TL;DR:** If you want [`tf.cond()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/control_flow_ops.html#cond) to perform a side effect (like an assignment) in one of the branches, you must create the op that performs the side effect **inside** the function that you pass to `tf.cond()`.

The behavior of `tf.cond()` is a little unintuitive. Because execution in a TensorFlow graph flows forward through the graph, all operations that you refer to in **either** branch must execute before the conditional is evaluated. This means that both the true and the false branches receive a control dependency on the `tf.assign()` op, and so `y` always gets set to `2`, even if pred is `False`.

The solution is to create the `tf.assign()` op inside the function that defines the true branch. For example, you could structure your code as follows:

```py
pred = tf.placeholder(tf.bool, shape=[])
x = tf.Variable([1])
def update_x_2():
  with tf.control_dependencies([tf.assign(x, [2])]):
    return tf.identity(x)
y = tf.cond(pred, update_x_2, lambda: tf.identity(x))
with tf.Session() as session:
  session.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
  print(y.eval(feed_dict={pred: False}))  # ==> [1]
  print(y.eval(feed_dict={pred: True}))   # ==> [2]
```

Comment: Yeah, that's the one that confuses me also. My understand is that before executing `tf.cond`, the runtime makes sure all the dependencies are executed. Dependencies of ops in `True` and `False` branches are also dependencies of `cond`, so even though an op in a branch may never be executed, all of it's dependencies are executed, does that that sound right?

Comment: Yep - the graph pruning considers all potential dependencies (of either branch) for execution, and only inhibits their execution if they were defined inside one of the branches, because the `CondContext` [adds a control dependency on the pivot](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/2b2f312cb07765c628d264abe326bfc286f462c1/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py#L1092) and that dependency will be a dead tensor (preventing the op from executing) if it is in the branch not taken.

Comment: What was the reasoning doing it this way? Why not prune the subgraph behind the non-active branch?

Comment: @LenarHoyt: The pruning happens **before** the value for `pred` has been computed. This enables TensorFlow to cache a single pruned graph based on a simple key (essentially the arguments to `Session.run()`), and makes the implementation of conditional execution simple and lightweight. The same mechanism is used to implement `tf.while_loop()`, where the advantages of performing the control flow at this level are more evident.

Answer (score 3):

```
pred = tf.constant(False)
x = tf.Variable([1])

def update_x_2():
    assign_x_2 = tf.assign(x, [2])
    with tf.control_dependencies([assign_x_2]):
        return tf.identity(x)
y = tf.cond(pred, update_x_2, lambda: tf.identity(x))
with tf.Session() as session:
  session.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
  print(y.eval())
```

This will get the result of `[1]`.

This answer is quite the same as the above answer. But what I wanna share is you can put every ops you would like to use in its branch function. Because, given your example code, tensor `x` is can be directly used by the `update_x_2` function.