# tf.cond not behaving as expected

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I have a question related to how tensorflow evaluates expressions in a `tf.cond` statement.

I use a custom operation that gives me batches of data of either type A or type B. Its signature looks like that

```
REGISTER_OP("GetData")
.Attr("path: string")
.Output("data: int32")
.Output("type: int32")
.SetIsStateful()
```

The `type` output is 1 for type A and 2 for type B. Depending on the type, I want to run a different (custom) operation, say `opA` or `opB`. Of course, their output has the same type. To express this data flow, I use `tf.cond` as in:

```
(data, type) = get_data(path = "...")

opA = op_a(data)
opB = op_b(dat

def perfromA():  return opA
def perfromB():  return opB

joined_op = tf.cond(tf.equal(type, tf.constant(1, dtype=tf.int32)), perfromA, perfromB)
```

I added some debug statements to `getData`, `opA` and `opB`. For a data sequence *ABA* I hope to get

```
getData: returning type A
opA:     got some data
getData: returning type B
opB:     got some data   
getData: returning type A
opA:     got some data
```

However, I do get

```
getData: returning type A
opA:     got some data
opB:     got some data
getData: returning type B
opA:     got some data
opB:     got some data   
getData: returning type A
opA:     got some data
opB:     got some data
```

Is this the expected behaviour? The result of the `joined_op` does correctly take the if-else into account but still, both operations are always computed. This is not only a computational burden but also defeats the purpose if `opA` and `opA` perform actions that affect variables (such as an optimization step).

**CORRECT SOLUTION** as pointed out by @Yaroslav

```
def perfromA():  return op_a(data)
def perfromB():  return op_b(data)
```

For a more detailed example, please see the dummy implementation of the three operations below:

```
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/op.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/lib/random/philox_random.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/lib/random/simple_philox.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace tensorflow;


REGISTER_OP("GetData")
.Attr("path: string")
.Output("data: int32")
.Output("type: int32")
.SetIsStateful();


class GetData : public OpKernel {
    public:
        explicit GetData(OpKernelConstruction* ctx) : OpKernel(ctx) {}

        void Compute(OpKernelContext* ctx) override
        {
            Tensor data(DT_INT32, TensorShape({}));
            Tensor type(DT_INT32, TensorShape({}));
            if(rng_.Uniform(2) == 0){
                type.scalar<int32>()() = 1;
                data.scalar<int32>()() = 100;
                LOG(INFO) << "returning type A";
            }
            else{
                type.scalar<int32>()() = 2;
                data.scalar<int32>()() = 200;
                LOG(INFO) << "returning type B";
            }

            ctx->set_output(0, data);
            ctx->set_output(1, type);
        }

    private:
        random::PhiloxRandom philox_ =  random::PhiloxRandom(10) ;
        random::SimplePhilox rng_ = random::SimplePhilox(&philox_);

};
REGISTER_KERNEL_BUILDER(Name("GetData").Device(DEVICE_CPU), GetData);


REGISTER_OP("OpA")
.Input("input: int32")
.Output("output: int32");

class OpA : public OpKernel {
    public:
        explicit OpA(OpKernelConstruction* ctx) : OpKernel(ctx) {}

        void Compute(OpKernelContext* ctx) override
        {
              const Tensor& data = ctx->input(0);
              LOG(INFO) << "A: got some data";
              ctx->set_output(0, data);
        }
};
REGISTER_KERNEL_BUILDER(Name("OpA").Device(DEVICE_CPU), OpA);

REGISTER_OP("OpB")
.Input("input: int32")
.Output("output: int32");

class OpB : public OpKernel {
    public:
        explicit OpB(OpKernelConstruction* ctx) : OpKernel(ctx) {}

        void Compute(OpKernelContext* ctx) override
        {
              const Tensor& data = ctx->input(0);
              LOG(INFO) << "B: got some data";
              ctx->set_output(0, data);
        }
};
REGISTER_KERNEL_BUILDER(Name("OpB").Device(DEVICE_CPU), OpB);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create opA/opB inside tf.cond

See the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37064128/419116)

Comment: Follow-up: So if opA was a whole graph of operations instead of a single custom-op, I would need to define the whole graph inside the operationA function, not just the last node?

Comment: Yup. The way TensorFlow executor works is that it only executes a node after it's dependencies are computed. "cond" node dependencies are same as dependencies of any other node, executor has no notion of lazy evaluation

Comment: Good to know. So I'll move as much of the graph into the opA/opB callables as possible to have an actual conditional computation.