# What's the difference between tf.cond and if-else?

Tags: tensorflow

What difference between tf.cond and if-else?

### Scenario 1

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = 'x'
y = tf.cond(tf.equal(x, 'x'), lambda: 1, lambda: 0)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(y))
x = 'y'
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(y))
```

### Scenario 2

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.Variable('x')
y = tf.cond(tf.equal(x, 'x'), lambda: 1, lambda: 0)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    init.run()
    print(sess.run(y))

tf.assign(x, 'y')
with tf.Session() as sess:
    init.run()
    print(sess.run(y))
```

The outputs are both `1`.

Does it mean only tf.placeholder can work, and not all the tensor, such as tf.variable? When should I choose if-else condition and when to use tf.cond? What are the diffences between them?

Comment: Your mistake in the code is the following: `tf,assign(x, 'y')` will simply create the assignment operation, but yet you need to run this operation so that you assign 'y' to x. Therefore, you to try something like that:

`ass_op = tf.assign(x, 'y')`

Then under `tf.Session()`, you need to add: `sess.run(ass_op)` That is when you will print 0.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`tf.cond` is evaluated at the runtime, whereas `if-else` is evaluated at the graph construction time.

If you want to evaluate your condition depending on the value of the tensor at the runtime, `tf.cond` is the best option.

Comment: Do you mean if-condition depends at  graph construction time, if at the runtime the condition changes, but it don't have effect on if block, because it is  determined  at  graph construction time.

Comment: thats exactly what I meant.

Comment: Look at the my update. Does it mean `x` need to be tensor, otherwise tf.cond can't work either?

Comment: Yes x should be a tensor; you may use some placeholder to feed the value

Comment: I try to use tf.variable, but failed. Look at the update. It is amazing. I have heard somebody use tf.variable, `is_training` to distinguish the training or test phase, and to change the condition of `dropout`. But I try, tf.variable can't work.

Comment: @gaussclb https://stackoverflow.com/q/37063952/5615276 is probably relevant to your last comment.

Comment: So, tf.cond is also differentiable? how about tf.where vs. if-else?

Answer (score 2):

Did you mean `if ... else` in Python vs. `tf.cond`?

You can use `if ... else` for creating different graph for different external conditions. For example you can make one python script for graphs with `1, 2, 3` hidden layers, and use command line parameters for select which one use.

`tf.cond` is for add *condition block* to the graph. For example, you can define [Huber function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huber_loss) by code like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
delta = tf.constant(1.)
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=())

def left(x):
    return tf.multiply(x, x) / 2.
def right(x):
    return tf.multiply(delta, tf.abs(x) - delta / 2.)

hubber = tf.cond(tf.abs(x) <= delta,  lambda: left(x),  lambda: right(x))
```

and calculation in Graph will go by different branch for different input data.

```
sess = tf.Session()
with sess.as_default():
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(hubber, feed_dict = {x: 0.5}))
    print(sess.run(hubber, feed_dict = {x: 1.0}))
    print(sess.run(hubber, feed_dict = {x: 2.0}))

> 0.125
> 0.5
> 1.5
```

Comment: Can I use if-else to replace tf.cond. I use if tf.abs(x)<=delta: huber=left(x); else: huber=right(x). Is it the same?

Comment: No, you can't use `if ... else` for add condition block to the graph.

Comment: No. It's not same, and it doesn't work. You should first *create* graph and when *launch* calculation. But you tried create graph and calculate at the same time.

Comment: if I use python variable to instead of tf.placeholder about x, and at runtime, I change the value x, will tf.cond judge condition again?

Comment: If you don't want to use TF you can do same calculation without it and use only Python.

Comment: Regards to update of your question. in `y = tf.cond(tf.equal(x, 'x'), lambda: 1, lambda: 0)` python variable `x` converted to the `tf.variable` in the `tf.Graph`, and you will can't change it by changing python variable `x`.

Comment: If I don't want to use tf.placeholder, do you have any way to change the value of x? Look at the update2, I failed.

Comment: And how does it connect to your initial question about "difference between tf.cond and if-else"?

Comment: I use tf.cond, but I don't want to use tf.placeholder as condition of tf.cond. Is there any way to use python variable or tf.variable instead of tf.placeholder? Your example just use tf.placeholder.

Comment: You can use `tf.variable` instead `tf.palceholder`, but anyway this variable will be calculated from some data, which you will feed to `Graph` by `tf.placeholder`, or by some `tf.contrib.Dataset` or by child of `tf.BaseQueue`. I think you should understand what do you want to do more clearly, and formulate a question.

Answer (score 1):

Since the graph in TensorFlow is static, you cannot modify it once built. Thus you can use if-else outside of the graph at anytime for example while preparing batches and etc., but you can also employ it while constructing the graph. That is, if the condition doesn't depend on the value of any tensor, for example the dimention(having been set) of the tensor or the shape of any tensor. In such scenarios the graph will not be changed due to the condition while excuting the graph. The graph has been fixed after you finished drawing the graph and the if-else condition would not affect the graph while excuting the graph.

But if the condition depends on the value of the tensor in it that condition should be **included in the graph** and hence tf.cond should be applied.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put: `if else` is how you do switch in *Python*, while `tf.cond` is how you do switch in *Tensorflow*. During running, `if else` is fixed in the compiled *Python* program, while `tf.cond` is fixed in the constructed *Tensorflow* graph.

You can think of `tf.cond` as the *Tensorflow*'s internal way of doing `if else`.