# How to have a truly conditional statement in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, control-flow

`tf.cond` evaluates both branches of the conditional. This is ridiculous and unintuitive to me. Is there a conditional operator that only evaluates ONE of the branches depending on the conditional?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: About the "unintuitive" part see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37064128/3767239). Why exactly you find it "ridiculous" you need to explain a bit more in detail. Note that tensorflow is "define-and-run" and hence constructs the graph before it is run (including all possible branches). [pytorch](https://pytorch.org/), which uses "define-by-run", can be used with normal `if/else` blocks and only includes the relevant branch.

Comment: @a_guest I understand how it works now. But is there a way to get a real "if statement" in tensorflow? That is, the if statement as asked in the question. I've been Googling a ton but can't find anything

Comment: I am still not sure what you exactly mean. In tensorflow, first the graph is created and then it is run by sending data into it. Since at graph creation time the relevant branches are not determined yet (otherwise you could just skip the irrelevant branch; this can be done by `if/else` during graph creation) both branches need to be considered and incorporated into the resulting graph. But again I am not sure what you mean by "real if-statement" and what you would need it for. What exactly do you think is problematic about the current behavior?

Comment: @a_guest Thanks for the response. So the actual problem: is that I have a py_func in each of the branches. These py_func's modify global variables. I thought only one branch would get executed -- but both are being executed and it's messing up my global variables.

Comment: Then you really have to rethink your design and probably read more about what tensorflow actually does. As I said, it's about creating a graph and then feeding data into that graph, collection output and performing other operations on that graph. I really cannot imagine where (and for what purpose) your global variables come into play. The graph is a separate space with input and output channels and that's it, no side effects intended. The graph could be run anywhere, on your GPU, on a remote server, ... It makes no sense that these operations would modify your local variables.

Comment: Could you post the minimal code here ?