# Create stateful counter with TF Dataset and Eager

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I'm trying to add an accumulator in my Tensorflow Dataset pipeline. Basically, I have this:

```
  def _filter_bcc_labels(self, labels, labels_table, bcc_count):
        bg_counter = tf.zeros(shape=(), dtype=tf.int32)

        def _add_to_counter():
            tf.add(bg_counter, 1)
            # Here the bg_counter is always equal to 0
            tf.Print(bg_counter, [bg_counter])
            return tf.constant(True)

        return tf.cond(tf.greater_equal(bg_counter, tf.constant(bcc_count, dtype=tf.int32)),
                                        true_fn=lambda: tf.constant(False),
                                        false_fn=_add_to_counter)


ds = ds.filter(lambda file, position, img, lbls: self._filter_bcc_labels(lbls, {"BCC": 0, "BACKGROUND": 1}, 10))
```

My goal here is to increment the `bg_counter` when the `tf.cond` `false_fn`is reached but my variable always has the value 0, it never actually increments.
Someone can explain to me what is happening?

Bear in mind I'm using TF eager and I can't use `ds.make_initializable_iterator()` then feed in my `bg_counter` initial value.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found an answer to my question thanks to @MPękalski for pointing me in the right direction. 
The code now looks like this:

```
def _filter_bcc_labels(self, bg_counter, labels, labels_table, bcc_count):
        bg_counter = tf.zeros(shape=(), dtype=tf.int32)

        def _add_to_counter():
            nonlocal bg_counter
            bg_counter.assign_add(1)
            # Prints the counter value
            tf.Print(bg_counter, [bg_counter])
            return tf.constant(True)

        return tf.cond(tf.greater_equal(bg_counter, tf.constant(bcc_count, dtype=tf.int32)),
                                        true_fn=lambda: tf.constant(False),
                                        false_fn=_add_to_counter)


bg_counter = tf.get_variable("bg_counter_" + step, initializer=lambda: tf.zeros(shape=[], dtype=tf.int32), dtype=tf.int32, trainable=False)
ds = ds.filter(lambda file, position, img, lbls: self._filter_bcc_labels(bg_counter, lbls, {"BCC": 0, "BACKGROUND": 1}, 10))
```

Keep in mind that this solution doesn't work if you iterate twice on your dataset as the counter doesn't get reinitialized in that case. And if you move `bg_counter = tf.get_variable("bg_counter_" + step, initializer=lambda: tf.zeros(shape=[], dtype=tf.int32), dtype=tf.int32, trainable=False)` inside the `ds.filter`then you get a `'Tensor' object has no attribute 'assign_add'` because of the eager mode.

If you really want to do it the right way then you have to create a counter when you iterate over your batches, outside of the dataset pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to wrap your counter in a class as Variables in Eager get deleted when they run out of scope.

**Code:**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function
import tensorflow as tf
tf.enable_eager_execution()
import tensorflow.contrib.eager as tfe

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(([1,2,3,4,5], [-1,-2,-3,-4,-5]))

class My(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = tf.get_variable("mycounter", initializer=lambda: tf.zeros(shape=[], dtype=tf.float32), dtype=tf.float32
                                 , trainable=False) 

v = My()
print(v.x)
tf.assign(v.x,tf.add(v.x,1.0))
print(v.x)

def map_fn(x,v):
    tf.cond(tf.greater_equal(v.x, tf.constant(5.0))
           ,lambda: tf.constant(0.0)
           ,lambda: tf.assign(v.x,tf.add(v.x,1.0))
           )
    return x

dataset = dataset.map(lambda x,y: map_fn(x,v)).batch(1)

for batch in tfe.Iterator(dataset):
    print("{} | {}".format(batch, v.x))
```

**Log:**

```
<tf.Variable 'mycounter:0' shape=() dtype=float32, numpy=0.0>    
<tf.Variable 'mycounter:0' shape=() dtype=float32, numpy=1.0>    
[1] | <tf.Variable 'mycounter:0' shape=() dtype=float32, numpy=2.0>
[2] | <tf.Variable 'mycounter:0' shape=() dtype=float32, numpy=3.0>
[3] | <tf.Variable 'mycounter:0' shape=() dtype=float32, numpy=4.0>
[4] | <tf.Variable 'mycounter:0' shape=() dtype=float32, numpy=5.0>    
[5] | <tf.Variable 'mycounter:0' shape=() dtype=float32, numpy=5.0>
```

**Working example:**
https://www.kaggle.com/mpekalski/tfe-conditional-stateful-counter

Answer (score 0):

I think what youre trying to do requires [assign_add()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/assign_add) method and not the add method. Note that the argument must be a Variable.

Also be careful with tf.cond for a generic use outside of eager. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37064128/10111931) is a discussion on the same.