# Using tf.cond() in an estimator model function to train a WGAN on a TPU causes doubled global_step

Tags: tensorflow, generative-adversarial-network, tpu

I’m trying to train a GAN on a TPU, so I’ve been messing around with the TPUEstimator class and accompanying model function to try to implement the WGAN training loop. I’m trying to use `tf.cond` to merge the two training ops for the TPUEstimatorSpec as so:

```
opt = tf.cond(
    tf.equal(tf.mod(tf.train.get_or_create_global_step(), 
    CRITIC_UPDATES_PER_GEN_UPDATE+1), CRITIC_UPDATES_PER_GEN_UPDATE+1), 
    lambda: gen_opt, 
    lambda: critic_opt
)
```

`gen_opt` and `critic_opt` are the minimize function of the optimizer I'm using, set to update the global step as well. `CRITIC_UPDATES_PER_GEN_UPDATE` is a python constant for just that and is part of the WGAN training. I've tried to find a GAN model using `tf.cond`, but all models use `tf.group`, which I can't use because you need to optimize the critic many more times than the generator. 
 However, every time I run 100 batches, the global step increases by 200 according to the checkpoint number. Is my model still training correctly, or is `tf.cond` just not supposed to be used this way to train GANs?

Comment: Can you please show how you use tf.cond?

Comment: Sorry about that! I posted this right before going to sleep, but now I've updated it.

Comment: mod(x, N) should give a result < N by the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tf.cond` is not supposed to be used in this way to train GANs.

You get 200 because every training step the side effects (like assignment operations) of **both** the `true_fn` and `false_fn` are evaluated. One of the side effects is the global step `tf.assign_add` operation that both optimizers define.

Hence, what happens is like

- Exeuctuion of `global_step++ (gen_opt)` and `global_step++ (critic_op)`
- Evaluation of the condition
- Execution of `true_fn` body or `false_fn` body (depending on the condition).

If you want to train a GAN using `tf.cond`, you have to remove all the side operations (like the assignment, hence the definition of the optimization step) from the outside of `true_fn`/`false_fn` and declare everything inside them.

As a reference, you can see this answer about the behaviour of `tf.cond`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37064128/2891324

Comment: Going off of your suggestion, I tried to implement it by defining the minimize function inside of the lambdas in the conditionals. However, now I'm getting an error indicating I don't have static shapes. Is there any way to mitigate this?

Comment: You should set the static shape of the object (if you know the shapes of that tensor at graph-definition time). You can get an idea about the shapes here: https://pgaleone.eu/tensorflow/2018/07/28/understanding-tensorflow-tensors-shape-static-dynamic/