# non-deterministic behavior for tf.cond on is_variable_initialized

Tags: tensorflow

Consider this demo code:

```
import logging
logging.getLogger('tensorflow').disabled = True
import tensorflow as tf
import sys

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()


def test_var_2():
  v = tf.Variable(initial_value=True, trainable=False, name="test_var_3")
  print("is initialized:", tf.is_variable_initialized(v).eval(), file=sys.__stdout__)

  def make_init():
    with tf.control_dependencies([tf.Print(0, ["var is not initialized", tf.is_variable_initialized(v)])]):
      return tf.variables_initializer([v])

  def on_already_init():
    return tf.group(tf.no_op(), tf.Print(0, ["var is initialized", tf.is_variable_initialized(v)]))

  maybe_init = tf.cond(
    tf.is_variable_initialized(v),
    on_already_init,
    make_init,
    name="init")
  with tf.control_dependencies([maybe_init, tf.Print(0, ["cd init"])]):
    x = tf.where(v.read_value(), True, False)

  print("x:", x.eval())
  print("is initialized:", tf.is_variable_initialized(v).eval(), file=sys.__stdout__)
  print("x:", x.eval())
  print("is initialized:", tf.is_variable_initialized(v).eval(), file=sys.__stdout__)


if __name__ == "__main__":
  test_var_2()
```

The output is non-deterministic. I either get this (1):

```
is initialized: False
.../logging_ops.cc:79] [cd init]
.../logging_ops.cc:79] [var is not initialized][0]
x: True
is initialized: True
.../logging_ops.cc:79] [cd init]
.../logging_ops.cc:79] [var is initialized][1]
x: True
is initialized: True
```

Or this (2):

```
is initialized: False
.../logging_ops.cc:79] [cd init]
.../logging_ops.cc:79] [var is not initialized][1]
x: True
is initialized: True
.../logging_ops.cc:79] [cd init]
.../logging_ops.cc:79] [var is initialized][1]
x: True
is initialized: True
```

Or this (3):

```
is initialized: False
.../logging_ops.cc:79] [cd init]
.../logging_ops.cc:79] [var is initialized][1]
x: True
is initialized: True
.../logging_ops.cc:79] [cd init]
.../logging_ops.cc:79] [var is initialized][1]
x: True
is initialized: True
```

The variant 3 (where the var is initialized at the first `x.eval()`) makes no sense at all to me. How can it end up in that cond-branch? Why is it suddenly initialized?

The difference between variant 1 and 2 is probably because the `tf.Print` is not fully evaluated as part of the `tf.control_dependencies`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an even more tricky case of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37064128/133374) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35739367/tensorflow-tf-cond-evaluating-both-pedicate). The point is that `tf.variables_initializer([v])` does not really creates a new op for the init (i.e. the assign to the initial value) but this assign-op was already created earlier (inside the `tf.Variable` constructor) and is just used here. Thus, my solution is to not use this initializer but to create my own, which must be created inside the `make_init` function, i.e.:

```
def make_init():
  with tf.control_dependencies([tf.Print(0, ["var is not initialized", tf.is_variable_initialized(v)])]):
    return tf.assign(v, True)
```

This solves the problem.