# tensorflow scatter_nd with empty tensors?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to smush two tensors together.  `scatter_nd` is perfect for this occasion, and I have written the following function to accomplish my task.  It basically just does 2 scatter_nds ad puts them together.

```
def tf_munge(t, i, r, j, axis=0):
    #insert tensor t at indices i and tensor r at indices j on axis `axis`.
    #requires: i.shape[0] == t.shape[axis] && j.shape[0] == r.shape[axis] && t.shape[k] == r.shape[k] ∀k != axis
    i = tf.expand_dims(i, -1)
    j = tf.expand_dims(j, -1)
    rank_indices = tf.range(tf.rank(t))
    roller = tf.roll(rank_indices, -axis, 0)
    rolled_t = tf.transpose(t, roller)
    rolled_r = tf.transpose(r, roller)
    scatter_shape = tf.concat((tf.shape(i)[0:1] + tf.shape(j)[0:1], tf.shape(rolled_t)[1:]), axis=0)
    scattered = tf.scatter_nd(i, rolled_t, scatter_shape) + tf.scatter_nd(j, rolled_r, scatter_shape)
    return tf.transpose(scattered, tf.roll(rank_indices, axis, 0))
```

It works as expected, generally.  However, it fails whenever both `r` and `t` are empty along some axis.  I have two code "paths" depending on a boolean wherein I split my tensor and perform different operations depending on whether that boolean is true or false.  Sometimes, that boolean is false for 0 rows.  In this case, I end up doing things to an empty tensor.  One of those things is this attempted scattering.  The error actually references the output shape (`scatter_shape` in the above code) claiming that:

> ValueError: Indices and updates specified for empty output shape for 'ScatterNd_4' (op: 'ScatterNd')
>   with input shapes: [3,1], [3,0,2], [3] and with input tensors computed as partial shapes: input[2] = [5,0,2].

Note that the axis that is empty is different than the axis along which I'm scattering.  Here is a working example:

```
foo = tf.ones((3,1,2))
bar = tf.ones((2,1,2))*2
i = tf.constant([1,3,4])
j = tf.constant([0,2])
tf_munge(foo,i,bar,j,axis=0)
#Output:  <tf.Tensor 'transpose_13:0' shape=(5, 1, 2) dtype=float32>
```

Here is a failing example:

```
foo = tf.ones((3,0,2))
bar = tf.ones((2,0,2))*2
tf_munge(foo,i,bar,j,axis=0)
#Output: The error above
```

The expected output here would obviously be an empty tensor of shape `(5,0,2)`.

I thought about using a conditional on the shape of the input, but `tf.cond` [executes both pathways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35739367/tensorflow-tf-cond-evaluating-both-pedicate).  How can I handle this situation when I have an empty tensor with `scatter_nd`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that more simply with [`tf.gather`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather) in a way that works for all cases:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def tf_munge(t, i, r, j, axis=0):
    tr = tf.concat([t, r], axis=axis)
    idx = tf.argsort(tf.concat([i, j], axis=0))
    return tf.gather(tr, idx, axis=axis)

with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
    foo = tf.ones((3, 1, 2))
    bar = tf.ones((2, 1, 2)) * 2
    i = tf.constant([1, 3, 4])
    j = tf.constant([0, 2])
    out = tf_munge(foo, i, bar, j, axis=0)
    print(sess.run(out))
    # [[[2. 2.]]
    # 
    #  [[1. 1.]]
    # 
    #  [[2. 2.]]
    # 
    #  [[1. 1.]]
    # 
    #  [[1. 1.]]]
    foo2 = tf.ones((3, 0, 2))
    bar2 = tf.ones((2, 0, 2)) * 2
    out2 = tf_munge(foo2, i, bar2, j, axis=0)
    print(sess.run(out2))
    # []
```